# What to consider Cash Flows in DCF analysis

Tags: taxes, cash-flow

When evaluating a project using discounted cash flow analysis, are cost savings (such as lower utility bills) as a result of taking on a project considered cash flows?

Also, should the increase in income taxes due to the reduced operating cost also be considered a cash flow?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to accounting. It's about discounted cash-flow analysis, which is relevant to investing (valuation).

Comment: thanks, which stack site should this have been posted on?

Comment: I think this one is appropriate.  That comment was for the mods - there is not a good stack site for accounting questions (but this is not an accounting question IMHO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. ALL cash flows related to the project should be considered, even if they represent adjustments to existing cash flows. So changes in *cash* expenses and taxes should be included in a DCF analysis.

Be careful, though, that you are measuring *cash* impacts only. Other non-cash impacts like depreciation should not be considered in a DCF analysis.